# How to formLogin() since WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, websecurity

I'm trying to test spring security. With WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter deprecated, I have some difficulties. I'd like to display the default connection form, previously displayed using .formLogin().

Here's my code:

```
package projet.auth.login.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager(){
        UserDetails user = User
                .withUsername("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();

        UserDetails admin = User
                .withUsername("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER");
                    auth.requestMatchers("/admin").hasRole("Admin");
                })
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

and
the rest controller for testing the different user

```
package projet.auth.login.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class LoginController {


    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getRandom()
    {
        return "Welcome to this web-app";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public String getUser()
    {
        return "Welcome User";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/admin")
    public String getAdmin()
    {
        return "Welcome Admin";
    }

}
```

How can i do that ?
Cause i can't connect the users i created.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

You can add default formLogin using this way(Spring 6.0),

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    return http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                auth.requestMatchers("/").permitAll();
                auth.requestMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER");
                auth.requestMatchers("/admin").hasRole("Admin");
            })
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).